# WPF C# .NET 4.7.2 / Index datagridcolumn and change format

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I just filled a WPF datagrid with sql server data with this code:

```
string strSqlHomeView = "select * from MyTable"
string connetionString = @"Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=SSPI";
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
SqlDataAdapter sqlDA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, cnn);
System.Data.DataTable Dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
sqlDA1.Fill(Dt);
MyDatagrid.ItemsSource = Dt.DefaultView;
cnn.Close();
```

But as it's data from SQL, it seems I cannot directly change the format from XAML, so I guess I need to index the column from the code behind. I just want to round 2 after comma.
In Winform, with a datagridview I would do like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["MyColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.##";
```

For those who use to play with Python Dataframe or C# winform datagridview, do you know how to set up things from column to column like an iloc function or an indexing.
Since the Microsoft doc isn't vey explicit about that, it's not that straightforward to find something relevant on the internet because each example has its own particularities.

Anyway, thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are auto-generated then you can handle `AutoGeneratingColumn` and set the format this way:

```
MyDatagrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += MyDatagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn
...
private void MyDatagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "MyColumn")
    {
        DataGridTextColumn col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "0.##" };
    }
}
```

Comment: ok cool that works ! I wanna add the ".AutoGeneratingColumn " is the event of the datagrid.
I have one question though, what does exactly represents the "e" ? It would be the argument of the event and this case the Column itself ??